# rest api get an array of javascript objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am consuming this public api, the problem I have is that it is selecting an array of objects within the object field and I cannot access these values in the console, it shows me this (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

const url = `https://catfact.ninja/facts`;

```
    const getFact = () => {
    return fetch('https://catfact.ninja/facts' ,
    {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }})
    .then(res => res.json())
    }
    const createFactDiv = (fact) => {
        const factContainer = document.createElement('div');
        const setup = document.createElement('p');
      
        setup.innerText = fact.data
        console.log(fact.data);
        factContainer.append(setup);
      
        return factContainer
      }
    const appendFact = (factDiv) => {
    const factContainer = document.getElementById('factContainer');
    factContainer.append(factDiv);
    }

    //This is unused
    /*
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    })
    */

    getFact().then ((fact) => {
    const factDiv = createFactDiv(fact);
    appendFact(factDiv);
    })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UMd9.png)

Comment: `(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]` is simply a condensed version of what's below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting tripped up because `getFact()` is actually returning a result set that contains a number of (potentially useful) properties. It should probably be called `getFacts()`, because the `.data` property contains an array of multiple facts.

Perhaps try looping over the data array and setting `setup.innerText` to `fact.fact` rather than `fact.data`?

```
const getFacts = () => {
    return fetch('https://catfact.ninja/facts' ,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }}).then(res => res.json())
    }

const createFactDiv = (fact) => {
    const factContainer = document.createElement('div');
    const setup = document.createElement('p');
  
    setup.innerText = fact.fact;
    console.log(fact.fact);
    factContainer.append(setup);
  
    return factContainer
  }

const appendFact = (factDiv) => {
    const factContainer = document.getElementById('factContainer');
    factContainer.append(factDiv);
}

//This is unused
/*
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    })
*/

getFacts().then(facts => facts.data.forEach(fact => appendFact(createFactDiv(fact))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a console.log(JSON.stringify(fact.data))

Comment: Hello, but how could I select the value to print it inside a bootstrap card, currently I get something like [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] ,[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: you could loop through the array and append there
for(const item of fact.data){

Answer (score -1):

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(fact.data));
```

Comment: Hello, but how could I select the value to print it inside a bootstrap card, currently I get something like [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] ,[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.